# How to reproduce Broken Pipe error in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a simple server application, communicating with a mongodb server, running on the port 1234. Sometimes i find the application hanging (not down, it would be better...) and this error on the log

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
  self.process_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
  self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
  self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
  self.finish()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
  self.wfile.close()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
  self.flush()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
  self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
**error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe**
```

I read about 'broken pipe' error and how to avoid it, but i don't really know *when* does it occur... So, there's a way to reproduce the problem or to debug it?

I don't know if the question makes sense without fully explaining what the server does, actually, but if i don't get some clue of the situation, I can't explain better than this...

Comment: This may be related, http://bugs.python.org/issue14574#msg252953

Comment: Great! If I open the webpage trying to communicate with the server and kill it instantly, the server remains stucked. So i can reproduce the error and try to fin out how to solve it. My version of python is 2.7.6, maybe an update would solve the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately Python 2.7.11 does not contain this patch, http://bugs.python.org/file40772/clear_buffer_on_error.patch

Comment: I'm starting to think it is simpler to catch the exception than to update the python version...